# How can I get this regex to allow spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex:

```
Regex strPattern = new Regex(@"^[]0-9A-Za-z&[@!*(){}:?.,^%#$~`;'_/\\-]*$");
```

I'd like it to allow spaces (any sequence of) but everytime I try to put it in here somewhere, it screws it all up. How do I get it in here? thanks!

Comment: What did you try exactly? Simply inserting a space in there should work fine.

Comment: Did you mean `@"^[0-9A-Za-z&][@!*(){}:?.,^%#$~\`;'_/\\-]*$"`?

Comment: I think you need to escape your special char (as well). 
e.g., A fullstop/period "." will match any char, so if you want to specifically match a fullstop you need to escape it "\." See: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Comment: @DarcyThomas Inside square brackets, `.` matches a literal dot. It's not a wildcard here.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The misplaced square bracket confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should work

```
Regex strPattern = new Regex(@"^[]0-9A-Za-z &[@!*(){}:?.,^%#$~`;'_/\\-]*$");
```